# Using the post-increment operator in initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list, post-increment

Can I use the post-increment operator with initialization list arguments? For example something like this:

```
template <class T> struct MyClass
{
  MyClass(T& val): myvar(val++) {/*body*/}
  protected: T myvar;
};
```

And will code in the constructor body be affected by the change?

Comment: What is the type of val and is it passed by reference or value?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I should change the function so it takes the variable `val` by reference, right? I think I made a mistake.

Comment: Well, your compiler will tell you. MyClass(val) is not going to compile because the type of val is missing, so obviously you should change it. What are you _trying_ to do anyway?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I just edited it.

Comment: I just wanted to know if the compiler would get back to the increment operator after returning the value of val as it would in functions and normal expressions.

Comment: It will apply the increment to val, of course. But I object to that behaviour. It's hard to think of anything less clear and more error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. The `myvar` member will have the value of `val` before the increment.

We should considere that val will have a type supporting the post-increment operator.

```
template <class T> struct MyClass
{
    MyClass(T val): myvar(val++) {/*body*/}
//          ^
protected:
    T myvar;
};

MyClass<int> foo( 1 );

// Here myvar will have the value 1
```

And don't forget the type of `val` passed to the `MyClass` constructor.